# Preprocessor with proxy design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c-preprocessor, proxy-pattern

In the proxy section the Design Patter from the Gang of Four says:

> Overloading the member access operator isn't a good solution for every kind of proxy. Some proxies
>   need to know precisely which operation is called, and overloading the member access operator
>   doesn't work in those cases.
>
> [...]
>
> In that case we must manually
>   implement each proxy operation that forwards the request to the subject.
>
> [...]
>
> Typically
>   all operations verify that the request is legal, that the original object exists, etc., before forwarding
>   the request to the subject. It's tedious to write this code again and again. So it's common to use a preprocessor to generate it automatically.

OK, which preprocessor and how in C++?

Comment: Sounds like it was Friday evening and somebody wanted to get home in a hurry …

Comment: The GOF book is hardly a great trove of good C++ practice.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical reference for implementing some Design Patterns in C++ is

> Modern C++ Design
>   by Alexandrescu

Another good reference for the techniques of using the type system of C++ for building design patterns is the book on

> C++ Templates
>   by Vandevoorde & Josuttis

And **the** reference for template meta-programming is

> C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools and Techniques from Boost and Beyond
>   by David Abrahams and Alesky Gurtovoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean automated generation of the wrapper code around the subject class. An example would be wrapper code generated by the [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) project.